# initialize Knockout ViewModel with json data before apply binding best practices

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a simple [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) ViewModel. but before i apply binding from that model to my view i need first to initialize it or set array value with some data (JSON format) that i 'll get from the server via AJAX.

I know i can create object of my model, make the ajax request then initialize my model array. Like this:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Servers = ko.observableArray([]);//this one 'll be filled by data from server
}
var MyViewModel = new AppViewModel();
MyViewModel.Servers = ko.mapping.fromJSON(json_data);//make ajax call to get json_data.
ko.applyBindings(MyViewModel);
```

Is that good practice or there is better one.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a fine way to do it to me, at least with the context you're providing. The [mapping plugin's documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) has a section about AJAX requests, and also concludes with an "advanced" section that helps you track the keys of server objects so that posting back updates to the server gets easier.

Another good source is the [loading & saving tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving). It doesn't use the mapping plugin, showing the more basic things about handling CRUD operations through AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

The Knockout Mapping plugin appears to be on it's way out.  The original author is/was [looking for maintainers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/knockoutjs/0cZAAVloRDw/KeswfigPmpoJ), at which point it seemed that consensus was to have users migrate to the newer [Knockout ViewModel plugin](http://coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/).

I don't know if it's best practice, but I'll chime in with how I'm doing the JSON-to-ViewModel step.  My VMs are fairly complex, so I keep them in a different js file and pass the data into the constructor.  That makes my in-page script look like this:

```
var MyViewModel = new AppViewModel(json_data);
ko.applyBindings(MyViewModel);
```

Having the single line makes it slightly more convenient in unit testing (one less thing to forget about).

Comment: sorry but i didn't get your point. can you explain more or help me with complete example